# AWS cloudformation : how to set cluster name when creating a AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup resource

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-cloudformation

I have a resource in the template of type AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup. When the stack is created, it is assigning a generated name when creating this cluster. Redis engine is being used. In case of AWS::ElastiCache::CacheCluster, there is a property called ClusterName which serves the same purpose. Is there a corresponding property here ?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

For me, setting the ReplicationGroupId property worked. I used an input parameter called "ClusterName".

```
Resources:
  RedisReplicationGroup:
    DependsOn: SecurityGroup
    Type: AWS::ElastiCache::ReplicationGroup
    Properties: 
      AtRestEncryptionEnabled: !Ref AtRestEncryptionEnabled
      AuthToken: !Ref AuthToken
      AutomaticFailoverEnabled: !Ref AutomaticFailoverEnabled
      CacheNodeType: !Ref CacheNodeType
      CacheParameterGroupName: !Ref CacheParameterGroupName
      CacheSubnetGroupName: !Ref CacheSubnetGroupName
      Engine: redis
      NumNodeGroups: !Ref NumNodeGroups
      ReplicationGroupId: !Ref ClusterName
      ReplicasPerNodeGroup: !Ref ReplicasPerNodeGroup
      ReplicationGroupDescription: "Redis Cluster"
      SecurityGroupIds: 
        - !Ref SecurityGroup
      Tags:
        - 
          Key: "Environment"
          Value: !Ref EnvironmentTag
        - 
          Key: "Name"
          Value: !Ref ClusterName
        -
          Key: "CreatedBy"
          Value: !Ref CreatedByTag
        -
          Key: "Project"
          Value: !Ref ProjectTag
      TransitEncryptionEnabled: !Ref TransitEncryptionEnabled
```